# Last existing revision of deleted file in SVN

Tags: svn, version-control

So I removed file X from SVN many moons ago, and I have the revision number of that delete.  I would like to know the revision number of the previous commit (i.e. the last existing version of file X).  CVS was sequential, so I could just -1, but this does not appear to be the case with SVN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Revision numbers in svn are sequential, too, it's just that they don't increase for every file on every commit. If the delete was revision number 246, then

```
svn co -r 245 url://svn/project
```

should give you the project state just before the delete. The file should be in there and you can

```
svn log filename
```

to get the last commit for the file.

Comment: +1. Also, without checking out: svn log -r 245 url://svn/project/filename

Answer (score 0):

```
svn blame filename -r123
```

Comment: To be clear, in this example you're assuming the delete was committed in *r124*, so that "svn blame filename -123" references the last version prior to the delete?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found, is to svn log parent_directory back to when the delete happened, and grab the rev number of the delete.

I am looking for this same issue. Will post something better if i find it.